# sinon spy not detecting a function call

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, chai

I'm trying to use sinonJS framework for nodeJS unit tests. The problem is, I cannot get the sinon spies working at all. This is my code:

```
const callback = sinon.spy(someModule.callback)

mainModule.doSomethingFunction() //someModule.callback function is called inside this function

assert(callback.calledOnce, 'callback should be called once')
```

It just fails with:

> AssertionError: callback should be called once

But I'm logging inside the function that should be called, and it clearly shows it is being called, the sinon spies just doesn't detect it. I wonder what is wrong?

Comment: If what you've included in your question is all of the code under test, it's not called. You create the spy and then do nothing with it.

Comment: I edited the question: I added the function inside the callback that is supposed to be spied on. Isn't the purpose of the spy to spy, and not do something with it? I thought the spy just spies, and then I can afterwards test whether the function it spied has been called?

Comment: @VilleMiekk-oja Yes, but nothing in your code ever calls  `callback`. Maybe it was supposed to be passed as an argument to `doSomethingFunction`?

Comment: It is called inside the mainModule.doSomethingFunction. Inside that mainModule.doSomethingFunction, it calls the someModule.callback function

Answer (score 2):

To wrap an object method in a spy, you can use `sinon` like this:

```
const callback = sinon.spy(someModule, 'callback');
mainModule.doSomethingFunction();
assert(callback.calledOnce, 'callback should be called once');
callback.restore();
```

Note that you should call `restore` when you are done to unwrap the spy.

Comment: Doesn't work =/. It just doesn't detect callback, even I wrote it exactly like you did it

Comment: It works fine for me in unit tests I have for some Node streams. The docs are [here](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sinonspy). If you cannot get it to work, you need to include a [mcve] in your question, as your question contains little code.

Comment: One difference is, that we use ASI with node. The automatic semicolon insertion. Maybe that can affect sinon so it doesn't detect the function call?

Comment: Also, we use dirty-chai with chai

Comment: Please see my new question related to the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868119/how-to-sinon-spy-module-export-utility-functions , you might be able to solve it

Answer (score 1):

The statement `const callback = sinon.spy(someModule.callback)` creates a spy that will call the `someModule.callback` once it is called (BTW it is not a constant) but it doesn't replace the `someModule.callback` function. To replace the function use `someModule.callback = sinon.spy(someModule.callback)`

Comment: Please see my new question related to the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868119/how-to-sinon-spy-module-export-utility-functions , you might be able to solve it